# Performance tuning complex SQL join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to make a join on 2 tables.

TableA

```
| date | var |
+------+-----+
| 1    | a   |
| 2    | b   |
| 3    | e   |
| 4    | c   |
| 5    | b   |
```

TableB

```
| date | var |
+------+-----+
| 1    | a   |
| 2    | b   |
| 3    | c   |
| 3    | d   |
```

I want to make an inner join such that date and var matches or if date in tableA is larger than the date in tableB match only on var in tableA with var in tableB where date in tableB is max.

The output table should be:

```
| date | var |
+------+-----+
| 1    | a   |
| 2    | b   |
| 4    | c   |
```

Here is what I came up with - but it is very slow:

```
select a.*
from tablea a
inner join tableb b on (a.var = b.var and a.date = b.date)
                    or (a.date > (select max(date) from tableb b) 
                        and b.var in (select var from tableb having max(date)=date))
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, show the results you want.  Also, you are only selecting columns from `a`, so `join` doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Column periode, in tableb?

Comment: @jarlh Ups. Type. corrected now

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am trying to delete some columns the do not match. I added en output table example. Hopefullye that makes it clearer.

Comment: Please explain the logic for the last two lines in the resultset:  (3, e) and (4, c)

Comment: I wouldn't really say this is especially a "complex" query either. It seems like, as well, that some of that `ON` should be in the `WHERE`, considering it's an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @GMB. I corrected the results table. Hopefully it makes more sense now. But generally if the date is in both tables match on date and var. if date in tableA is larger than date in tableB merge on var where var in tableB has max(date)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b 
ON a.var = b.var AND b.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM TableB WHERE a.date >= date)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d8faa267642a4a5f1a74b9ee34a0d73c).
Results:

```
> date | var
> ---: | :--
>    1 | a  
>    2 | b  
>    4 | c
```

Comment: If this is what you meant then yes. But your original sql implies something different see my answer below. It returns the same results for the data set you gave, but will return different results for a different data set. You should clarify your spec to indicate what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to predict performance without knowing exact shchema, including indexes. On a heap, I bet the query below would be more performant.

```
DECLARE @a TABLE(date INT, var NVARCHAR(1))
INSERT @a VALUES(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'e'),(4,'c'), (5,'b')

DECLARE @b TABLE(date INT, var NVARCHAR(1))
INSERT @b VALUES(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(3,'d')

;
WITH b AS
(
    select * from(
        select var,date,dateRankReveresed = rank() OVER(ORDER BY date DESC)
        from @b 
    )as x
)


select a.*
from
    @a a
    inner join b b on a.var=b.var 
                    and 
                    ((a.date=b.date) 
                    or 
                    ((a.date > b.date and b.dateRankReveresed=1)))
```

EDIT : in this situtation use rank instead of row_number as you need ties for dups.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql doesn't work in MySQL but I changed it to:

```
 select a.*
 from TableA a
 inner join TableB b on (a.var = b.var and a.dat = b.dat) OR (a.dat > (select 
 max(dat) from TableB) 
                    and b.var in (select var from TableB where TableB.dat= 
 (select max(dat) from TableB)));
```

but I get more results that way.

```
'1', 'a'
'2', 'b'
'4', 'c'
'4', 'c'
'5', 'b'
'5', 'b'
```

Instead I think you want:

```
select a.*
from TableA a
where (a.dat > (select max(dat) from TableB) 
        and a.var in (select var from TableB 
                  where TableB.dat=(select max(dat) from TableB)))
union select a.* from TableA a inner join TableB b where a.var=b.var and 
a.dat=b.dat;
```